# Handling Action Bars with two fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I have a layout with two fragments and both fragments have their own action bars, each of which have their own action items and menus.  When my app is in landscape mode and both fragments are displayed on the screen, it looks like the framework is choosing to display the action bar on the "right" (or the 2nd fragment), which means the fragment on the left (1st fragment) is missing its action items and menu options.

Everything works fine when the app is in portrait mode, so I'm not sure if I should be doing something to handle the fragments when they are both displayed.  Thanks.

EDIT

In each of my fragments I'm using this code to add menu items to the Action Bar:

In fragment 1:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, final MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_menu_1, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

In fragment 2:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, final MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_menu_2, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

UPDATE:

Apparently using `setRetainInstance(true)` is what caused the menus not to refresh.  I was using that because I have an AsyncTask that was throwing an exception if the device was rotated.  So I fixed one issue, but broke another.

Comment: There is a post here to provide the answer to this question http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-action-items-from-within-fragments/

Comment: [Fragments in action bar tutorial](http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2013/07/simple-fragments-tutorial.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're thinking about this incorrectly. The action bar is not displayed as part of any fragment, but actually as part of the activity. If you declare in your fragments that you provide action items via `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`, then all will be displayed as part of the action bar. You can then take the appropriate action by overriding `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`.

Comment: Check out the OP, I added some code, but I'm inflating a menu layout in both of my fragments in onCreateOptionsMenu.  Shouldn't the Action Bar then show both menus?

Comment: did you call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in both?

Comment: Yea, because in portrait mode, when the fragments are on different screens, each fragment's menu displays correctly.  I should also note that I'm using ActionBarSherlock, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: I've never used ActionBarSherlock, but what I'm describing is how it would be expected to work using `android.app.Activity`. I know it works, because that's how I do it :).

Comment: So you have two fragments, each with the own menu options and when both fragments are displayed on the screen, the menu options for each fragment are merged into one?  Knowing what I should expect to see may help me debug this issue.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have a "menu" fragment and a "content" fragment both displayed, both with their own action items.

Comment: That's good to know, I must be doing something wrong then.  Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Just so I'm sure, even when you rotate your device the menu options display as they should, ie, in portrait it only shows the fragment that is being displayed menu and when you rotate to landscape, the menu combines?  My issues is the menus are getting messed up when I rotate from landscape to portrait and vice versa, not when I start the app in landscape or portrait.

Comment: Sorry, I have my app locked in landscape for tablets. I would expect only the visible fragment menus to show if I only had one fragment container.

Comment: Ah, ok, so at least I pinpointed my issue to something is not setup right when rotating the device.  Thanks again for your responses.